# Mono framework shebang linux

Tags: linux, bash, mono, shebang

I have a c# source file. Is there any way to put something like #!/usr/bin/env mono, so it will be compiled and then run as executable:

For python for example, i'll do like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

In fact, what I want is to run the script without calling "mono the.exe", after compiling. I want something like "./the.exe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: I just noticed you want to do this for a single source file—for a single source file. This is almost supported by the `csharp` REPL that ships with Mono. However, the REPL spits out a syntax error because it doesn't understand the shebang line and sees it as a preprocessor definition. If I misunderstood and you were talking about a compiled assembly, the below text still applies. **/EDIT**

You can't use shebangs, because .exe files produced by Mono are PE executables, just like on Windows. They contain CIL, not a script.

What you can do though is produce a small shell script that runs `mono your.exe` and use that, or you can use the Linux kernel's binfmts support, as outlined [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Registering_.exe_as_non-native_binaries_.28Linux_only.29).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to use [`update-binfmts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/update-binfmts.8.html) to register `mono` as the interpreter for (compiled) mono programs.

Try `update-binfmts --display` and see if the output includes something like:

```
cli (enabled):
     package = mono-common
        type = magic
      offset = 0
       magic = MZ
        mask =
 interpreter = /usr/bin/cli
    detector = /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli
```